# Firebird 2.1 generator increment value by more than one problem

Tags: concurrency, transactions, generator, firebird

I have a problem with a Firebird generator that is incremented by more than one even if I am calling it with the `GEN_ID` function and 1 as increment value this generator is used in one stored procedure and it is following another generator incremented in the same way, but it's consistent with the increment of one here is the core of the stored procedure:

```sql
create procedure insert_proc (
    Type integer)
returns (
    Op1 integer,
    Op2 integer)
as
begin

if (:Type = 0) then
begin
  Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1);
  Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1);
END

Insert Into Table1(Op1, Op2) VALUES(:Op1, :Op2);

end
```

The only place that this generator is incremented by one is this stored procedure same as the first generator, the first generator is always incremented by one but the second generator sometimes is incremented with values other than one example 6 or 3.

This procedure is called in the context of the same transaction and committed correctly because the first generator is always sequential, but the second generator is sometimes off by variable value.

I didn't try anything yet because the code is correct, but it seems that I must be lacking some information on the transaction level or it could be something related to the database or the version of the Firebird server, that's why I need some expertise here.

Comment: Are you sure that second generator is not used anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Firebird generators are outside transaction control, and stored procedures are not atomic operations. This means that if another connection or another transaction also increments the generator (e.g. by calling the same stored procedures), the generating of values can be interleaved.

That is, with two transactions, T1 and T2, there are several orderings of operations possible:

```
T1: Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1); (T1:OP1 = 1)
T1: Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1); (T1:OP2 = 1)
T2: Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1); (T2:OP1 = 2)
T2: Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1); (T2:OP2 = 2)
```

```
T1: Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1); (T1:OP1 = 1)
T2: Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1); (T2:OP1 = 2)
T1: Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1); (T1:OP2 = 1)
T2: Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1); (T2:OP2 = 2)
```

```
T1: Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1); (T1:OP1 = 1)
T2: Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1); (T2:OP1 = 2)
T2: Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1); (T2:OP2 = 1)
T1: Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1); (T1:OP2 = 2)
```

```
T2: Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1); (T2:OP1 = 1)
T1: Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1); (T1:OP1 = 2)
T2: Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1); (T2:OP2 = 1)
T1: Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1); (T1:OP2 = 2)
```

```
T2: Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1); (T2:OP1 = 1)
T2: Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1); (T2:OP2 = 1)
T1: Op1 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP1, 1); (T1:OP1 = 2)
T1: Op2 = GEN_ID(GEN_OP2, 1); (T1:OP2 = 2)
```

The middle example, order T1, T2, T2, T1, would be an example of introducing a gap for T1. Add more concurrent transactions and the possible combinations explode, and the differences may increase.

There is not a real solution to this, other than that you shouldn't care about it, or you should always use a single generator, increment it by 2, and use the returned value for one column, and returned value - 1 for the other (but that could have other implications for your data model, and would basically indicate that you don't need two columns and only one would suffice, so I wouldn't recommend doing this).